# libCURL doesn't follow redirects (even with FOLLOW_LOCATION 1L)

Tags: c++, network-programming, libcurl

I'm trying to write a code snippet which downloads from sourceforge. This is the code, as you may note I explictly set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION but it seems it has not effect

```
int main(void) {
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    const char *url = "http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpc-hc/files/MPC%20HomeCinema%20-%20x64/MPC-HC_v1.7.7_x64/MPC-HC.1.7.7.x64.exe";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "/home/snake91/example.exe";
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"w+");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fwrite(buffer2.c_str (), buffer2.length (), sizeof(char), fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Looking for a solution I found there is a parameter for CURL (-L) which does the job, is there something equivalent for the lib?

ps this is the output of the VERBOSE flag...

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 216.34.181.60...
* Connected to sourceforge.net (216.34.181.60) port 80 (#0)
> GET /projects/mpc-hc/files/MPC%20HomeCinema%20-%20x64/MPC-HC_v1.7.7_x64/MPC-HC.1.7.7.x64.exe HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)
Host: sourceforge.net
Accept: */*

* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: BigIP
* HTTP/1.0 connection set to keep alive!
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 3047
< 
* Connection #0 to host sourceforge.net left intact
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-L sets CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

**But**, as you can see in the response headers you get a 200 OK back and that's not a HTTP redirect so there's nothing for libcurl to follow. If that URL indeed has a redirect, it is either done with a HTML meta refresh tag, or it is made using javascript - neither which libcurl supports.

Comment: thanks, at least now I know it's not possible...do you know some other library that does the job?